# Does LAST_INSERT_ID(col - 1) always produce unique numbers?

Tags: mysql

given the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (col_pk INT)
```

will the following always produce a mytable unique col_pk even if hundreds of clients issue the statement concurrently:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col_pk) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(col_pk - 1))
```

(I am using InnoDb and am asumming since the INSERT runs in a transaction it should be safe that (LAST_INSERT_ID(col_pk - 1) produces a  unique number for  mytable)

Comment: You have to design your application in such a way that it ensures this.

Comment: I am asking because the docs reads: "For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis." So maybe duplicates could happen?

Comment: Use locking to restrict concurrency and allow single process at a time.

Comment: I am using InnoDb and am asumming since the INSERT runs in a transaction it should be safe that (LAST_INSERT_ID(col_pk - 1) produces a globally unique number ?

Comment: I think the database system should handle that on its own.

Comment: Why do you need a PK that decrements? Would it be terribly bad to let the application invert it or use an insert hook to put a negative copy of the PK into a separate field?

Comment: this is a simplified example  the table has a index on col_pk and positive values indicate that the row is valid. A negative value indicates that the row is temp which may become valid. I cannot use null because of the index on the column

Answer (score 0):

In the case you show above it will not generate a unique identifier.

You need to have a field that is primary key for the table *AND* defined as "AUTO_INCREMENT".
With both those requirements it should return unique numbers for that table.
Not globally unique across tables.

Have a look at this part of the documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: I can not use AUTO_INCREMENT since col_pk contains only negative numbers.  Sorry for the  "globally" misunderstanding. I just mean unique for table mytable

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your insert query well enough. Last insert ID was introduced to be able to retrieve the value generated when inserting into an auto_increment table. This value is, by design, not shared among connections.